# Symfony2 cannot connect to localhost

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I am trying to start my first symfony2 application and i am following the instruction from symfony but seems i am doing something wrong and can not figure it what i am doing wrong. this is what i have done(running on mac) ---

```
    **$ curl -LsS http://symfony.com/installer > symfony.phar
    $ sudo mv symfony.phar /usr/local/bin/symfony
    $ chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/symfony
    $ symfony new my project
    $ cd myproject/
    $ php app/console server:run**
```

[image: error message show]
        it show this error although i have edit at my php.ini file - extension=php_intl.dll
        and when i try to browse http://localhost:8000/ it shows ---
[image: cannot connect]
        can anyone help me what i am doing wrong. 
        Thanks a lot in advance ..

Comment: Please, can you show your web server config?

Answer (score 1):

Like Anna Adamchuk said you can set default time zone un **php.ini**

```
date.timezone = Europe/Paris
```

And you can use [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.ini-set.php) this at the begining of your php file

```
ini_set('date.timezone', 'Europe/Paris');
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve warning about timezone you have to uncoment in you php.ini and set default time zone:

```
date.timezone= date.timezone =Europe/Paris
```

Also check your web server configuration -> [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html)